# Remove comma from end of this string?

Tags: php, trim

When echoing `$teststring` I get the string below from the foreach loop. I needed to remove the trailing comma and tried `echo rtrim($teststring,',');` this removes commas from inbetween each bracketed set of data. How can I remove only the last comma?

Thanks

`[Date.UTC(2013,15,6), 9 ],[Date.UTC(2013,15,7), 9 ],[Date.UTC(2013,15,8), 9 ],[Date.UTC(2013,15,9), 9 ],[Date.UTC(2013,15,10), 9 ],[Date.UTC(2013,15,11), 9 ],[Date.UTC(2013,15,12), 9 ],`

I need to remove the trailing comma

```
foreach ($filtered_decoded as $results) {

   $date = str_replace("-",",",$results['date']);
   $pos = $results['position'];

    $arr = array("data"=>"[Date.UTC(".$date."), ".$pos." ],");

    // Tried to remove comma.
    $teststring = implode($arr);
    echo rtrim($teststring,',');
}
```

Comment: do it OUTSIDE the loop, or you just trimming ache piece, not the finial strong

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing comma in your expression here:

```
$arr = array("data"=>"[Date.UTC(".$date."), ".$pos." ],");
                                                      ^       Remove this
```

Then outside the loop use

```
$teststring = implode(",", $arr);
```

That should create your required string without the trailing comma